# stored procedure for each row of an outer stored procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I am new to stored procedures and am using mysql. I am creating the procedures in phpmyadmin.

What I need to achieve is a stored procedure which will return all user details from one table and their associated relations in a linking table.

I need my php web service to call the procedure and be able to return a json similar to the following:

```
{
    "userID": "2222",
    "userName": "mr x",
    "userAddress": "street, town, County",
    "userMobile": "1111",
    "userPhone2": "2222",
    "latitude": "53.2802937",
    "longitude": "-9.0515995",
    "relations": [
        {
            "relID": "3333",
            "relFName": "Mr",
            "relSName": "rel1",
            "relAddress": "street2, town2, county2",
            "relPhone": "3333",
            "relPhone2": "3333",
            "relType": "Brother"
        },
        {
            "relID": "4444",
            "relFName": "ms",
            "relSName": "rel4",
            "relAddress": "street 4, town 4, county 4",
            "relPhone": "4444",
            "relPhone2": "4444",
            "relType": "Friend"
        }
    ]
}
```

I currently have two stored procedures i.e.

getUsers:

```
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY userSName DESC;

END
```

and getRels:

```
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM relations WHERE relations.userID = UserIDParam;

END
```

But I'm not sure how to link them, before using sps, I had two queries. The outer one retrieved user details and the inner query was executed for each row in the results set of the first i.e. getting the relations array for each user. However when I switched from basic queries to calling stored procedures I get the error that commands are out of sync.

I can't seem to find an example of what I'm trying to achieve. Any help appreciated

**UPDATE**
the php code looks something like this:

```
$fetch = mysql_query("CALL getUsers();");

                while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($fetch)){

                        $GetRelations_Query = "CALL getRels();";
                        $relations_results=mysql_query($GetRelations_Query);
                        $relations_arr = array();

                        while ($InnerRow = mysql_fetch_array($relations_results)){

                            $relationsReturned = array('relID' =>$InnerRow['personID'], 'relFName' => $InnerRow['FName'], 'relSName' => $InnerRow['SName'], 
                            'relAddress' => $InnerRow['Address'], 'relPhone' => $InnerRow['Phone'], 'relPhone2' => $InnerRow['Phone2'], 'relType' => 
                            $InnerRow['relationship']);

                            array_unshift($relations_arr,$relationsReturned);
                        }


                            $row_array = array('userID' => $row['userID'], 'userName' => $row['userName'].' '.$row['userSName'], 'userAddress' => $row['userAddress'],
                            'userMobile' => $row['userMobile'],'userPhone2' => $row['userPhone2'], 'latitude' => $row['latitude'], 'longitude' => $row['longitude'], 'relations' => $relations_arr);

                            array_unshift($return_arr,$row_array);
                }
```

and error is Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given referring to the line `'while ($InnerRow = mysql_fetch_array($relations_results)){'`. I know that when I print out the error associated with that query, I am retrieving the error message stated above i.e. commands out of sync

Comment: How does relations table look like?
Looks like a simple `JOIN` for me.

Comment: I'm sorry, seems that's not what you're asking for. Can we see the PHP file for mysql fetching part? Seems to be rather PHP issue and not releasing result set on the connector.

Comment: @m_wilczynski will update question

Comment: All clear now. Please see my response.

Comment: Little update with one more solution I would recommend and second I would not (but still should work).

Answer (score 0):

I dig up a little and it seems that old `mysql` way of connecting to MySQL DB is **not supporting multiple stored procedures** at once. Not without going multiple connections which is (as you probably would guess) a not so good idea.
You might stay with `mysql` that I don't recommend as PHP docs say that:

> > This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.
> >     See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more
> >     information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> mysqli_query()
>
> PDO::query()

As in: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

**This is how I understand your current data model:**

[Link to SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8082d/1)

**Recommended solution:**

I would recommend to go to updated and newer `mysqli` as `mysql` will probably disappear in some time from PHP at all.

**Second recommended solution:**

You can also connect two stored procedures into one. Just join the two tables in one `SELECT` on `userID` and query using parameter you're providing.
Also I can see `UserIDParam` in your stored procedure but can't see it used in your code. Anyway, remember to prevent yourself from **SQL Injection**.
Stored procedures don't always protect you from such:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2011/02/16/do-stored-procedures-protect-against-sql-injection.aspx

**Not recommended solution - alternative:**

First get all the users at once.
Clear results set after using `getUsers`.
Then iterate on this result with second stored procedure `getRels`.

Comment: My issue is that each user can have an ARRAY of relations (of varying lengths) so I'm unsure how to implement the second recommended solution you have provided?

Comment: If you JOIN two tables on userid and then look with parameter, you got the same result: resultset of relations for given user (user you passed as parameter).

Comment: Something like `SELECT * FROM Users JOIN relations ON relations.userID = Users.userID ORDER BY userName DESC`; I dunno for what for are you using the param in general but you can add `WHERE` clause if you want to.

Comment: Maybe I am missing something or maybe I am not explaining myself. User A could have 7 relations, each of which has their own set of associated details. The way your query is written, it would only allow for one relation per user? Or am I missing something?

Comment: No, it wouldn't limit it that way, provided it's 1:N relationship.
But it depends how your relations table looks like. Does it have relationship defined with user table? If you don't know, can you at least provide columns that you have in relations table?

Comment: I've added 'How I understand your data model' SQL fiddle, please check if that's how it looks like now. If not, let us know the correct model.

Comment: Where can I access your fiddle? Yes the relations table contains a foreign key of userID which links to the primary key of the user's table

Comment: Click the link in my answer. Alternatively: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8082d/1